# Excel 2007 macro to copy paste values based cell value

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I need to write a macro that compares the date in B1 with the date in columns D1.DB1.  If they match, the column that matches needs to be copied and paste values. This is what I have done so far.  But it is not working.

```
Sub MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim i As Integer

Sheets("data").Range("B1").Select

For i = 4 To 56

If Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, i).Value = "B1" Then
Range(1, i).Select
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: ...and what is your problem with that? What have you done so far? Please show us a code.

Comment: I added the code I have written so far, but it is not working.

Comment: ...and what is wrong with the code? Do you get an error or it does not work as you want?

Comment: It moves the cursor to B1 but does not change the formulas to values for the column with the same date as B1.  I do not get an error message.

Comment: Please show me an example of date in `B1` and dates you want to compare. Are those dates in date format or just a value in a cell?

Comment: B1 has '8/9/2014', without the quotes it is formatted as a date mm/dd/yyyy. Cells D1 to DB1 have dates entered as well in same format.  In addition, these cells have conditional formatting to indicate which cell matches the date in B1.

Comment: One more question, where do you want to paste your dates?

Comment: I want to paste values over the formula that are in the cells.  So, I select the column where the date matches and then do a copy/paste values, this hard codes the values in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim i As Byte, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

For y = 3 To 73

    For i = 4 To 56

        If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & 1).Value Then

            ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Cells(y, i).Value

        End If

    Next i

Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: So now you can accept it as an anwser - if someone is going to look for similar problem he can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all: avoid using `.Select` method, it is very risky and can harm your data.

You do not need to select cell if you want to do something with it. Also if you want to compare one cell value with another, you should use `Range()` or `Cells()`. You used `"B1"` which means you were checking for value `B1` not for value of `Cell B1`.

**Edit:**

Not sure if this is what you want so lets give it a try. `y` represents row number and `i` represents column number. For each `y` there will checked all cells in columns `i`. They will be checked with a date in row `y` in column B.

```
Sub MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim i As Byte, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

For y = 3 To 73

    For i = 4 To 56

        If ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & y).Value Then

            ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Cells(y, i).Value

        End If

    Next i

Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response and explanation.  I believe this code is setting the number in 'Cells(1,i) to a value , which it already is. What I need to do is set all the formulas in rows 3 thru 73 of Column i to values.

Comment: Just to be sure. Not only you want to go through all columns from 4 to 56 but also to all rows from 3 to 73? Do you want to check whole range D3:BD70?

Comment: The first row of data in columns D thru BD (D1.DB1) Contain a date. If that date matches the date shown in B1, I need to convert the formulas in rows 3 thru 73 to values for the column "i" = to "B1".

Comment: If date matches with B1, you want to change all cells in column `i` rows 3 to 73 to value = "B1"? Like D3:D73 will have a value = "B1"?

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the effort you took to help me out. I only had to change one thing on the line the read...... If ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & y).Value Then............ If ws.Cells(B, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & 1).Value Then.............

Comment: Not sure how did you change it but your code: `If ws.Cells(B, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & 1).Value Then` is incorrect. `Cells()` property needs numeric arguments and you put `B` as row argument.

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say 'If ws.Cells(1,i)' not 'If ws.Cells(y,i)... Here is the complete macro if this helps: Sub_MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim i As Byte, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

For y = 3 To 73

    For i = 4 To 56

        If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = ws.Range("B" & 1).Value Then

            ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Cells(y, i).Value

        End If

    Next i

Next y

End Sub

Comment: You can post it as an anwser or I can edit my post and paste it.

Comment: I posted the macro as requested.  Thanks again.  Let me know if I need to do anything else.